# Add row including each variable value to existing dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 80 existing rows and 6 variables, they are:
Row_ID
CatName
CatAge
Request
Friends
ID,

and I need to add some outliers to the dataset of generated data by adding a row on to the end containing specific data.

I attempted the following but it does not work. Any tips on how to get this to work?

````
```{r, create row 1, echo=TRUE,include=TRUE} 
Cat_dataframe %>% 
add_row(Row_ID = "30",CatName = "Carla",CatAge="30",Request="30",Friends="8",ID="500000")
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command looks pretty good to me:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~"Row_ID", ~"CatName", ~"CatAge", ~"Request", ~"Friends", ~"ID",
              "1", "name1", "31", "request1", "2", "051245")
df %>%
  add_row(Row_ID = "30",CatName = "Carla",CatAge="30",Request="30",Friends="8",ID="500000")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   Row_ID CatName CatAge Request  Friends ID    
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr> 
#> 1 1      name1   31     request1 2       051245
#> 2 30     Carla   30     30       8       500000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You may have an issue with your chunk title (i.e. try `{r create_row_1, echo=TRUE, include=TRUE}` instead of `{r, create row 1, echo=TRUE,include=TRUE}`) and you may have an issue with different data types, e.g. if "CatAge" is an integer in your original dataframe and a character string in your add_rows() command (age=31 and age="31" are different types).

If you edit your original question to include the error message/s you're getting it will very likely make it easier troubleshoot your problem.